# T test using column variable from 2 different data frames in R

Tags: r, testing, multiple-columns, t-test

I am attempting to conduct a t test in R to try and determine whether there is a statistically significant difference in salary between US and foreign born workers in the Western US. I have 2 different data frames for the two groups based on nativity, and want to compare the column variable I have on salary titled "adj_SALARY". For simplicity, say that there are 3 observations in the US_Born_west frame, and 5 in the Immigrant_West data frame.

```
US_born_West$adj_SALARY=30000, 25000,22000
   Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY=14000,20000,12000,16000,15000

#Here is what I attempted to run: 

    t.test(US_born_West$adj_SALARY~Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY, alternative="greater",conf.level = .95)

However I received this error message: "Error in model.frame.default(formula = US_born_West$adj_SALARY ~ Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY')" 

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thank you!
```

Comment: Try `t.test(US_born_West$adj_SALARY, Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY, alternative="greater",conf.level = .95)`

Comment: that worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`US_born_West$adj_SALARY` and `Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY` are of unequal length. Using formula interface of `t.test` gives an error about that. We can pass them as individual vectors instead.

```
t.test(US_born_West$adj_SALARY, Immigrant_West$adj_SALARY, 
       alternative="greater",conf.level = .95)
```